# how to show last li on click in j query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so what i am trying to achieve is that when i click on the button 
the below content should scroll that much that it should only show 
the last li item in the list , i am using j query for this but not
working.

```js
  $('button').click(function() {

    var m = "-680px";
    $('ul').animate({
      marginLeft: '+=' + m
    }, 500);


  });
```

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
}
ul {
  width: 2000px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('ul').find('li:last-child').offset().left` and use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Code goes here 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('button').click(function() {
  var width = $('ul').find('li:last-child').css('width');
  var m =-($('ul').find('li:last-child').offset().left);
   var left = parseInt(m)+parseInt(width);
   alert(left);
   $('ul').animate({
     marginLeft: '+=' + left
   }, 500);
 });  
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Tv6o4dYaq7FtqpRtBfzw?p=preview

Comment: why it is showing second last li it should only show the last li i am trying to improve the code , can you suggest something ?

Comment: var m =-($('ul').find('li:last-child').offset().left);
   var left = parseInt(m);

Answer (score 0):

You can use .last() to get last occurrence of an element.
`$( "li" ).last()`